# What kind of statement did i do to compute the range of tax

Tags: c#, mysql

Hello everyone goodevening! im looking for help... what statement i use to compute the taxes range and the basic pay is in the label and i gather it to compute here's the photo of my mini payroll
MY PAYROLL[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3vHS.png)

THE RANGE OF TAX[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQxW7.png)

i try this logic but he cannot convert my text salary in my label

```
        public void witholdingtax()
    {
        int[] tax =  {10417,16666};
        double value = 0;
        if (tax[0] < 10417)
        {
            label18.Text = "0.0";
        }
        if(tax[0] > 10417)
        {

            value = tax[0] - 10417 * 0.20;
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MqvI.png)

Comment: You could improve this question by adding sample data from your tables and expected output as text. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please provide your tables here. Images can not help as we can not copy content. As suggested expected output will be more helpful